# ¿Cómo puedo hacer validador de que un código tiene premio?

Tags: javascript, html, sql

Llevo ya tiempo intentando hacer de forma simple, una pagina en la que se pueda comprobar si un código tiene premio o no.  (ejemplo: https://www.mundofacundo.com/)

De momento se me ha ocurrido la idea de este html+js

```js
function enviarTramite(evt) {
    valor = document.getElementById("codigo").value;
    if (valor === "000") {
        location.href = "https://www.google.es/";
        evt.preventDefault(); // Evitamos el submit en nuevos navegadores
        return false; // Evitamos el submit viejos navegadores
    } 
     else if (valor === "100") {
        location.href = "https://www.yahoo.es/";
        evt.preventDefault(); // Evitamos el submit en nuevos navegadores
        return false; // Evitamos el submit viejos navegadores
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HTML</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script src="code.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="codSeguimiento" onsubmit="enviarTramite(event);" method="POST">
    <p>Comprobar codigo</p>
    <input id="codigo" name="codigo" type=text maxlength="10">
    <br>
    <input id="boton" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Consultar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

En este ejemplo, cuando el usuario pone 000 se le enviaría a una pagina en la que apareciese como que es ganador de una Ps4 (por ejemplo) y si es 100, se le enviaría a otra pagina en la que apareciese que no ha ganado.

El problema de esto, que al comprobar el código se envía a otra pagina (aumentando la carga del servidor) y que cualquiera puede ver los códigos que están premiados.

¿Alguna ayuda o sugerencia?

Comment: Deberías hacer la comprobación desde servidor, no desde la parte de front.

Comment: Como bien dice César, la validación debe ser en servidor. Con un simple servicio REST API, puedes invocarlo mediante una llamada desde el front que envíe el código y ese servicio haga la comprobación correspondiente y te devuelva el resultado. Además, deberías, por una parte hacer el código a enviar con cierta complejidad ya que si no es muy fácil realizar N llamadas al servicio hasta adivinar el correcto y por otro limitar el número de llamadas por IP para evitar esto mismo.